# Color coding using HTML inside Perl

Tags: html, perl

```
$html -> holds the html table code
$query ->holds the data fetched from table(Oracle)
```

I'm inserting the data from $query to $html with color coding based on the conditions

**Code:**

```
while (my @rec =  $query->fetchrow_array() ) {
  my $file_status = $rec[9];
  my $data_status = $rec[11];
  my $data_status2 = $rec[13];

  if ($file_status eq "Files Received"
    || $data_status eq "Data Not Found"
    || $data_status2 eq "Partial Data") {
    # This changes the font color for all columns in a single row.
    # Is there a way to color code only the specific column?
    $html=$html."\n<font size=3 color=#F12A3D>"; 
  }
  else {
    $html = $html."\n<font size=3><tr>";
  }

  foreach my $x (@rec) {
    if (! defined $x) {
      $x = "";
    }
    $html = $html."<td>$x</td>"
  }
  $html = $html."</tr>"
}
```

Please let me know if i can color code the specific columns using html inside perl if the column values matches the condition(Example if column 8="a" for a record then i have to print the row with only column 2 in red color). If needed i can share the complete perl code of this script.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Please lay out your code so that it is readable. It's the least you can do when asking for free help to get it working.

Comment: `/-- ... --/` doesn't create a comment in Perl, or in any language that I know.

Comment: What about changing the `<td>`, not the whole `<tr>`?

Comment: I've reformatted your code to make it easier to understand. You're welcome, but please do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's 2017. We do not use `<font>` tags in HTML any more. It's a far better idea to set classes on your HTML tags and then use [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) to change the appearance.

If you want to colour individual table cells rather than the whole row, then it's just a case of moving the logic into the code where you're generating the table cells.

```
foreach my $cell_data (@rec) {
  $cell_data //= ''; # Convert undefined values to empty strings
  my $class;

  if ($cell_data eq 'a') { # for example
    $class = 'hilite';
  }
  $html .= '<td';
  $html .= " class='$class'" if $class;
  $html .= ">$cell_data</td>";
}
```

I'd also point out that putting raw HTML in your Perl code like that is a pretty bad idea. I'd highly recommend looking at a [templating solution](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
for( my $i=0; $i<@rec; $i++) {
  my $x = $rec[$i] // '';
  if( $i == 1 && ($rec[7]//"") eq 'a' ) {
    $html .= "<td><font size=\"3\" color=\"#FF0000\">$x</font></td>";
  }else{  
    $html .= "<td>$x</td>";
  }
}
```